# How to fix Image loaded by Glide from Disappearing on API Level 23?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm loading images from the phone's storage using Glide and for some reason, it will briefly flash and then disappear. This only happens on API 23 which is my min. Anything higher and it works as it should.

I found this question that is practically identical to my situation ([Image Loaded by glide appears then quickly disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460518/image-loaded-by-glide-appears-then-quickly-disappears)), but none of the fixes listed work for me. I have a suspicion that my images may be too large, but I am using the appropriate folders (drawable-hpdi,drawable-xxhpdi, etc...) so I should be using the image that would fit best on the device. I've tried adjusting my layout widths, heights, and anything else people have tried but have had no luck.

Here is the code I use to load my images:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(imageFromPhone)
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(placeHolderImage))
                .into(view);
```

And here is my XML for my ImageView:

```
<com.example.CustomPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pager1"
            android:contentDescription="Pager"/>
.
.
.
```

Once I'm in the activity that has my image it will briefly flash the image (weirdly it shows up a bit higher than usual). Then it will completely disappear and is gone for the rest of the time the app is open.

Comment: Add all the logcat you have during image loading and disappearing. Your problem is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the app some more I found out that I was using a photo that was fully transparent and for some reason in Glide or Android API 23 that made the color the same as the background, but that image was on top of the hierarchy. To fix this problem I needed to change the Alpha for my ImageView to 0.0f when I was using the transparent images and it fixed it.